# Unable to rename a column in python pandas dataframe after a merge(inner join)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes :
df1 columns are *token, last_price*
df2 columns are *token, symbol, date*

df1 and df2 have some rows where the token are the same. I need to extract those rows and have a dataframe with columns like this :
*Token Symbol Last_price.*

For this I do an inner join

df3 =  pd.merge(df1, df2, on='token', how='inner)

I get the dataframe df3 as
*token, symbol, last_price, date*

When I try to rename, the columns say symbol to Symbol,
e.g. `df3.rename(columns={'symbol', 'Symbol'}, inplace=True)`
I get an error
*TypeError: 'set' object is not callable* 
similarly, if I try to retain only three of the columns  and not have the date
e.g. df3 = df3[df3['token', 'symbol','last_price']]
I get a KeyError

it looks to me that after the merge, there must be something else that needs to be done in order to be able to operate on the data frame. I have looked through the documentation, but could not find anything in particular. Can anyone please help out?

Thank you for any inputs

Comment: your rename syntax is incorrect, you are using a set instead of a dictionary, should be --> `df3.rename(columns={'symbol': 'Symbol'}, inplace=True)`, as for the key error, remove the `df3` from the inner index

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am so embarassed :-(. I must have stared at the code for at least 30 minutes and did not see the  colon: vs comma error,. Ditto with the statement on setting the columns. Thank you again.